# Create Viewmodel to post data and display data in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am creating one form. I have viewmodel.I have one form there i have client_id,Emp_id and submit button. When the submit button clicked, below i want to display some data. This is my view model.

```
public class GroupVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MyItem> Items { get; set; }
}
Public class MyItem
{
public string client_id {get;set;}
public string emp_id {get;set;}

public string Label { get; set; }
public string Value { get; set; }
public string Emp_id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Currently this is view  code.

```
@model IEnumerable<GroupVM>
@foreach(var group in Model)
{
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                @foreach(var item in group.Items)
                {
                    <th>@item.Label</th>
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>@group.Name</td>
                @foreach(var item in group.Items)
                {
                    <td>@item.Value</td>
                }
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

In this view i want textboxes for client_id and emp_id. Now problem is if i put @model IEnumerable in view header i cant put textboxes for client_id and emp_id. So should i change my viewmodel? When i click on submit button, based on emp_id and client_id i have written query to get data and it will bind to model.
This is my controller code to bind data to model.

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    var table = new List<MyItem> {
        new MyItem { Label = "DocumentNumber", Value = "12345678", Emp_id = 1, Name = "First" },
        new MyItem { Label = "ExpiryDate", Value = "1/1/2015", Emp_id = 1, Name = "First" },
        new MyItem { Label = "IssueLoc", Value = "India", Emp_id = 1, Name = "First" },
        new MyItem { Label = "DocumentNumber", Value = "SecondValue", Emp_id = 2, Name = "Second" },
        new MyItem { Label = "ExpiryDate", Value = "SecondValue", Emp_id = 2, Name = "Second" },                
    };
    var data = table.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => new GroupVM
    {
        Name = x.Key,
        Items = x
    });
    return View(data);
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to filter the data in the view based on the values you enter in the textboxes for `client_id` and `Emp_id`?

Comment: Yes exactly. Currently emp_id in my Myitem i hardcoded. I want to pass it from front end.

Comment: i added emp_id and client_id to my MyItem class. I tried something like this in view. @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Client_Id but it saysdoes not contain definition for client_id so should i change my viewmodel?

Comment: In that case you models do not make sense. I can see an `Emp_id` in you `MyItem` model for filtering, but what is the purpose of the `client_id` propery?

Comment: client_id is also there. If i able to write textbox for emp_id then i can go ahead by adding client_id also.

Comment: And do you really want just a textbox for entering the `Emp_id`? Surely a dropdownlist where you can select from a known list would be more appropriate than expecting the user to guess what the value might be

Comment: As per requirement there is textbox so i think i cannot change

Comment: Yes i added emp_id and client_id in GroupVM viewmodel but still i am not getting intelligence at x=>x.client_id. Should i change my header in view?

Comment: Just realized what your doing - you need another view model from those properties - I will add an answer shortly

Comment: yes exactly. I thought of something viemodel nesting but i am new to mvc so just confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another view model with contains the properties for `client_id` and `emp_id` and a collection of `GroupVM`

```
public class SearchVM
{
    public string ClientID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<GroupVM> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

and in the view

```
@model SearchVM
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ClientID)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmployeeID)
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
@foreach(var group in Model.Groups) // change
{
    .... // as before
}
```

and change the `Test()` method to

```
public ActionResult Test(string clientID, string employeeID)
{
    // filter your data based on the parameters, for example
    var data = table.Where(x => x.Emp_id == EmployeeID).GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select( ..... );
    SearchVM model = new SearchVM
    {
        ClientID = clientID,
        EmployeeID = employeeID,
        Groups = data
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Side note: Using a textbox for entering an ID property does not seem appropriate and you should consider using a dropdownlist that renders the names of each `Employee` (but posts back the `ID` value). You can also consider using ajax to to post the values to a controller method that returns a partial view of the table and update the DOM without leaving the page to improve performance.

Comment: Thank you Stephen. I will check in my solution and mark it answered. again thanks a lot

Comment: I was not sure where `ClientID` fitted into it, but you will need to check that the `clientID` and `employeeID` parameters have actual values (and adjust you query to suit).

Comment: Yes sure. actually this is small example to understand the concept I posted here. My real project contains lot of tables and fields. If I understand the basic I can implement in the way I want.  As soon as I tested I will make answer as marked. Thanks a lot

Comment: If i want to initialize model in GET method then SearchVM model=new SearchVM() { Groups=???  } ; Little confused...

Comment: What are you not understanding? The model in the view is `SearchVM` so you need to initialize a new instance of it and pass it to the view. Then so that the textboxes retain the same value when your submitted the form, you set the values of properties `ClientID` and `EmployeeID ` and you also set the collection property based on your filtered data so that it can be rendered in the view

Comment: When the first tome view is loaded i do not want to display anything just client_id and emp_id user has to enter. As soon as enter data and hits on submit control should come to Test (POST) method, do filtering based on clientid and display required data in view. So when first time page loads Test(GET method) i want to intialise my viewmodel otherwise it will throw error saying that object instance cannot be set to null

Comment: finally i got what i need. you are really great.

Comment: No, you need to always initialize the view model, but just check if the parameters `clientID` and `employeeID` have values. If not then initialize it with `Group = new List<GroupVM>` so it returns an empty collection. That will ensure you do not throw and exception, but the table(s) will not be rendered

Comment: You will probably also want to include `[Required]` attributes on those properties so you get client side validation (and the form will not be able to be submitted if invalid)

Comment: Where i should vote? Yes i initialised and its working fine. I did not get vote? What is that?